# How does hemoglobin adhere to cotton?

Tags: organic-chemistry

Blood stain on cotton t shirt.How exactly does hemoglobin connect to the fabric? The blood stain if washed in warm water can become very long lasting,being able to remain after many washing cycles.

From chemical perspective,how does it stick to the cellulose based fabric as found in cotton t shirts?

Comment: Denaturated proteins act as glue.

Comment: Building on what @aventurin said: There's a [load of *other* (real) proteins in blood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_proteins), which exist in amounts far greater than hemoglobin. Large sized molecules give rise to a whole host of reactive fragments that probably end up reacting with some portion of cellulose (not sure, but the three $-OH$ groups on each cellulose monomer sounds like a good place to start). Good question though!